# Curve / Line fitting in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, linear-regression, curve-fitting

I am plotting a graph between Level and Discharge of a river. And then, I want to fit a line across the scatter points. 
My data frame df1 has 4704 rows and 2 columns - Discharge and Level.

```
fit  <- lm(df1$Level ~ df1$Discharge)
xx <- seq(0, max(df1$Discharge), length = 4704)
plot(x = df1$Discharge, y = df1$Level, pch = 19)
lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(x = xx)), col = "red")
```

Instead of getting a straight line, I am getting something else.

[image]

I want to know, Is there any way to get a straight line which fits the scatter points? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you provide the data, from what I can see, doing predict without providing a data.frame with the correct variable name might be causing the problem. If I rerun your code on some data:

```
set.seed(100)
df1 = data.frame(Level=runif(4704))
df1$Discharge=20*df1$Level + runif(4704)
fit  <- lm(Level ~ Discharge, data = df1)
xx <- seq(0, max(df1$Discharge), length = 4704)
plot(x = df1$Discharge, y = df1$Level, pch = 19)
```

This line throws an error:

```
lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(x = xx)), col = "red")
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Discharge' not found
```

If you change the column names it work:

```
lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(Discharge = xx)), col = "red")
```

Please provide a reproducible example.